# How to change position of account dashboard section in magento 2 my account

Tags: magento2

How to reorder the account dashboard overview section as shown below

**for example in the dashboard we have**

1. Recent Orders Section
2. Account Information Section
3. Address Book Section

**So I need to reorder like this**

1. Account Information Section
2. Recent Orders Section
3. Address Book Section

[image]

Comment: are you want to do this for Magento 1 or Magento 2? Because of the screenshot is for Magento 1.

Answer (score 1):

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_index.xml

Add the below code and flush the cache.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <move element="customer_account_dashboard_address" destination="content" after="customer_account_dashboard_top"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Check this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and add sortOrder value as per your need and requirement:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order History</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">220</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Suppose you want Account Information Section first and Recent Orders Section
after, than give Account Information sortOrder smaller value than the other.